# How to calculate $avg of array items in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

i am building up a `mongodb` `aggregation` query in which i have a computed field(array) of numeric values. And i have to find avg of the whole array field. My `mongodb` aggregation query is like this

```js
[{$match: {
  nsp: '/globalintltd.com',
  agentEmail: 'ahmed1549@globalintltd.com'
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'messages',
  let : {cid : '$_id'},
  pipeline:[
    {
      $match : {
        $expr:{
          $eq: ['$cid', '$$cid'],
        },
        type: 'Agents'
      }
    },
    {$limit : 1}
  ],
  as: 'messages'
}}, {$project: {
  agentEmail: 1,
  convDate: {
    $dateFromString:{
      dateString: '$createdOn'
    }
  },
  firstReplyDate:{
    $dateFromString:{
      dateString:{
        $arrayElemAt:['$messages.date', 0]
      }
    }
  }
}}, {$addFields: {
  difference: {
    $divide:[
      {
         $subtract:[
    '$firstReplyDate',
    '$convDate'
    ] 
      },
      60000
    ]
  }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: {
    "agentEmail" : "$agentEmail"
  },
  AgentFirstResponses : {
    $push : "$difference"  
  }
}}]
```

from above query i am getting results like this

```js
[
  {agentEmail : "ahmed1549@globalintltd.com", convId : 3434345111, AgentFirstResponses : [33.54,65.65,9.087,5.43]},
  {agentEmail : "ahmed1549@globalintltd.com", convId : 3434345112, AgentFirstResponses : [3.54,65.165,19.087,1.43]},
  {agentEmail : "ahmed1549@globalintltd.com", convId : 3434345113, AgentFirstResponses : [63.54,654.65,19.087,5.43]},
  {agentEmail : "ahmed1549@globalintltd.com", convId : 3434345114, AgentFirstResponses : [33.54,65.65,9.087,5.43]}
]
```

and i want to apply `$avg` for this field in my `aggregation` query. How can i do that to get the average of the whole array using `mongodb`?

I want the result like this

```
{
  "agentEmail" : "ahmed1549@globalintltd.com",
  "AvgFirstResponse" : 23.665(what ever average will of the whole array)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $push with $avg like this:

```
[{$match: {
  nsp: '/globalintltd.com',
  agentEmail: 'ahmed1549@globalintltd.com'
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'messages',
  let : {cid : '$_id'},
  pipeline:[
    {
      $match : {
        $expr:{
          $eq: ['$cid', '$$cid'],
        },
        type: 'Agents'
      }
    },
    {$limit : 1}
  ],
  as: 'messages'
}}, {$project: {
  agentEmail: 1,
  convDate: {
    $dateFromString:{
      dateString: '$createdOn'
    }
  },
  firstReplyDate:{
    $dateFromString:{
      dateString:{
        $arrayElemAt:['$messages.date', 0]
      }
    }
  }
}}, {$addFields: {
  difference: {
    $divide:[
      {
         $subtract:[
    '$firstReplyDate',
    '$convDate'
    ] 
      },
      60000
    ]
  }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: {
    "agentEmail" : "$agentEmail"
  },
  AgentFirstResponses : {
    $avg : "$difference"  
  }
}}]
```